# Access facebook profile information

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am planning to come up with a website to access the profile information of my friends on Facebook. The first step being is to authenticate a friend with their facebook user name and password. I am reading up on the docs on [manually authenticating a user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/). I am unable to understand that once I have a access_token, what steps I need to take to get a user information, in this case, even me?

What I also do not understand is the website states to provide the `app_id` and `app_secret` to generate the `access_token`. My understanding was that `access_token` would be needed for  user. So where does the example code authenticate a user? I am guessing that I haven't understood the login flow properly. If there are any other references, please let me know.

Comment: Are you able to get the access token??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the **access token**, simply use it with your calls. For eg:

```
$res = json_decode(file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN));
```

**EDIT**

The token: `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` is the **app access token**, not the user access token; so it has nothing to do with the user and it wont understand `/me`. And its power is just.

The other token that is received by the **login** flow (as mentioned in the link you've mentioned in the question) is the **user access token**, and it understands `/me`. It has the power to do anything that user has granted the app to.

Comment: Thanks for replying Sahil. This would help, but I am not able to understand is how does `graph.facebook.com/me` maps to my user account. All I have provided for generating the token was the `app_id` and `app_secret`